How does Google Meet do this borderless popup?
I'm wondering how they implemented a minimal window like this. I did not find any window.open parameter to achieve the same easily. I'm guessing it needs at least some validation like HTTPS or some Web Apps?

Trying any combination of window.open parameters didn't yield the same result easily. It seems the topic also evolved since earlier questions were answered. Debugging through the app also is no easy feat.

It likely uses something like navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia to get a browser dialog.  This window is not a javascript "modal"/"dialog" not opened with window.open

Isn't that https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Picture-in-Picture_API ?
